# Code seems to require Powershell 4, however, can't see why

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

So I built a powershell tool using forms.... and it works... there is nothing wrong with the code below, save for it will not work in Powershell 3.  It has to be 4.. and I can't find anything about this that is specific to 4.0.

I've looked through all the technet pages for the cmdlets I'm using and they all have the same functions listed for 3 and 4.

Any ideas?

basic function is this...

1. It clears 4 texts boxes.
2. it looks at a checkboxlist and provided only one item is checked it will 
   read in the data in that file and look for words that start with #.
3. If it finds a match greater than 4 in length... I'm assuming a single variable found since all the ones we will will be more than 4 letters long.  I did this because if only one is found the .count will not work. But if 4 matches occur the .length will be 4.. same as if the length of a single item was 4.
   If the length is 4 or less I am processing as 4 or less individual variable.
4. I now pass those into the text and accessiblename fields on the form

then in either case.. I update the status bar.

Nothing special.

```
$btn_LoadOptions = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btn_LoadOptions.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 8.25)
$btn_LoadOptions.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(156, 184)
$btn_LoadOptions.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(168, 23)
$btn_LoadOptions.TabIndex = 11
$btn_LoadOptions.Text = "Load Options"
$btn_LoadOptions.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$btn_LoadOptions.add_Click({btn_LoadOptions_Click($btn_LoadOptions)})

function btn_LoadOptions_Click($object)
{
    clean-messageboxes
    if ($cbl_DefaultMessageChoices.CheckedItems.Count -eq 1)
    {
        $regex = [regex]'(#\w+)'
    $found = Select-String -Pattern $regex -path $messagechoice -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
    if ($found.Length -gt 4)
    {
        $tb_MessageOption1.Text = $found
        $tb_MessageOption1.AccessibleName = $found
    }
    else
    {
        $tb_MessageOption1.Text = $found[0]
        $tb_MessageOption1.AccessibleName = $found[0]
        $tb_MessageOption2.Text = $found[1]
        $tb_MessageOption2.AccessibleName = $found[1]
        $tb_MessageOption3.Text = $found[2]
        $tb_MessageOption3.AccessibleName = $found[2]
        $tb_MessageOption4.Text = $found[3]
        $tb_MessageOption4.AccessibleName = $found[3]
    }
    $sb_TOC_PowerTools.Text = "Message Options Loaded"
}
else
{
    $sb_TOC_PowerTools.Text = "No message choosen"
}
}

function clean-messageboxes 
{
$tb_MessageOption1.Text = ""
$tb_MessageOption2.Text = ""
$tb_MessageOption3.Text = ""
$tb_MessageOption4.Text = ""
}
```

Comment: and yes I know I could use some shorter code in the else {}

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on "will not work"? Does it behave differently? Does it throw errors?

Comment: so... when I click the button on the form.. if you have powershell 3 installed.. nothing happens.. if you have 4 installed.. the file is read, and the options 1 to 4 of them load into the boxes no issues.

Comment: So from what you've seen so far, it actually sounds like the `btn_LoadOptions_Click` function never gets called. Could you show us the part where you register the Click event handler?

Comment: added to the post at the beginning

Comment: BTW, if you have access to ISE On Steroids it has compatibility check - will give you exact reason what is 4.0 only feature.

Comment: Nested function calls produce some quirky scoping issues in v 3.0 and earlier, try with `$btn_LoadOptions.add_Click($function:btn_LoadOptions_Click)` instead

Comment: Will try and let you know

Comment: So.. that had no change.. but I think I found out what is happening.. it's not because of anything in there.. is the origin of $messagechoice   I have this set to run without a shell.. so it's just the popup window... and I run it with the shell on the box with ps3.. and I get an error

for this line
    $global:messagechoice = $pgmessagedefaults_path + "\" + ($cbl_DefaultMessageChoices.CheckedItems.ForEach({$f = ($_ + ".txt");return $f}))

Comment: Method invocation failed because [system.string] doesn't contain a method named  foreach.  


so it looks like that will need to change if I need this to work in Ps3.. Not sure why I didn't do that before.. but since I didn't get errors on my 2 test systems.. I didn't think to run it with a console on the others..

Comment: Since $messagechoice is effectively blank.. nothing happens when you click the button

Comment: The .ForEach() method is a 4.0 feature - use |ForEach-Object{} instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention in the comments that you assign the `$messagechoice` variable like this:

```
$global:messagechoice = $pgmessagedefaults_path + "\" + ($cbl_DefaultMessageChoices.CheckedItems.ForEach({$f = ($_ + ".txt");return $f}))
```

The `.ForEach({})` extension method is [a PowerShell 4.0 feature](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26489.powershell-4-0-where-and-foreach-method-syntax.aspx), which explains why it doesn't work in PowerShell 3.0

Use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet instead:

```
$global:messagechoice = $pgmessagedefaults_path + "\" + ($cbl_DefaultMessageChoices.CheckedItems |ForEach-Object {$_ + ".txt"})
```

Comment: Yup.. that's what I thought after I saw the error.. I looked up that command.  I'll give that a try to make sure it works... Since I had to do the $f = , return $f.. can I do that command like this..

`$global:messagechoice = $pgmessagedefaults_path + "\" + ($cbl_DefaultMessageChoices.CheckedItems |ForEach-Object {$f = ($_ + ".txt"); return $f})`

it didn't seem to work correctly the other way without that.. I couldn't just do the $_ . ".txt" part... the path was messed up that way